# How do I change (String ...params) argument list in doInBackground asyncTask in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parameters, params-keyword

by default from api for asyncTask the signature for it is  doInBackground(Param ...params)

in my app I have this signature:

```
public String doInBackground(String ...params)
```

I tried and changed to this:

```
public String doInBackground(String param, int x)
```

but it gives me error:

> class DataTasker must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...params)

I know this 3 dots is an array and i can access it like

params[0] , params[1].

But still confused, in my main activity class I want to pass this data for background task: a string , an integer

```
DataTasker data = new DataTasker() ;
data.execute("mister x " , 56) ;
```

But apparently, i must pass only one argument

Comment: Why don't you pass the arguments as: new DataTasker("mister x", 56) ?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi, i did it gives me errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ,

Convert the integer into String and pass it wih the "mister x"

```
DataTasker data = new DataTasker() ;
data.execute("mister x " , String.valueOf(56)) ;
```

You can access both values as params and convert the second parameters into integer again

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    String user=params[0];
    int value = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is create an extension of AsyncTask where the desired parameter for the doInBackground is an Object. Something like this:

```
 private class DataTasker extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
```

This way you can do your parameter casting inside the `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 3):

> But apparently, i must pass only one argument

No, you can pass as many as you want. They all have to be the same base type.

Some options:

1. Declare the type as `Object`. This will require lots of casts.
2. Declare the type as `String`, pass in a `String` representation of your `int`, and convert it back later on.
3. Pass one or the other parameter via a `DataTasker` constructor.
4. Pass one or the other parameter via a setter on your `DataTasker`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Object instead of String and then it iwll look like `public String doInBackground(Object ...params)`. And you also will have to cast params[0] , params[1] to needed you types.